# How do i create a simple .js javascript file type?

Tags: javascript

I have this code in a text file:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;


  public class JavaFileReaderExample {

      public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

          FileReader FR = new FileReader("C:\\Temp\\test.txt");  // could throw FileNotFoundExceptions

          int temp =  FR.read(); //could throw IOException

          while(temp!= -1)  //-1 = EOF (End Of File)
          {
              System.out.print((char)temp);  // typecast to char in order to print char, not a number
              temp = FR.read(); //could throw IOException
          }
      }

  }
```

I saved it as: myjs.js
But in fact the file name is: myjs.js.txt
I want it to be js so i can read the file in my website as java script.

EDIT

I tried to use this code in this site:

http://voidexception.weebly.com/reading-from-a-text-file-using-a-java-filereader.html in the bottom they say you can read a text file from the hard disk ? FileReader FR = new FileReader("C:\projects\MyText.txt");   so i did: FileReader FR = new FileReader("C:\Temp\MyText.txt"); Saved  the file as java and in my site editor i call it in the html code:  but it's not showing the content of MyText.txt on me web.

Comment: that's not javascript...

Comment: But your code is not javascript at all.

Comment: [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) are only related by name. If you want to develop for client-side web, you'll want to learn and use the latter.

Comment: Did you mean how to save this as a .java file?

Comment: Do you have access to a terminal? If so, you can just rename the file using the command mv myjs.js.txt myjs.java

Comment: If you want to create an actual javascript file for the web, just save it with the .js extension, and make sure you put actual javascript code inside :)

Comment: What i wanted to do in general was to read content of a text file on my hard disk local file and display it's content on my own web . I still dont get it how to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is Java, not Javascript, so it can't be run by a web browser.

If you want to save it as ".js" anyway, you can, just like I can save anything as "filename.txt.java.jar.foo.bar.baz.exe", probably just by renaming it from my filesystem. But this won't really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a few things mixed up. The code you're trying to run is [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), not [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript). Try following a [simple tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_placement.htm) to get started with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

as other mentioned, your code above is not in javascript.

Anyway, if you want to save file in text editor with preferred extension, you may try to save it with double quote included when the program ask for the file name

"myjs.js"